# Positive lookbehind in regex in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, negative-lookbehind

I am using this regular expression `/(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )/` which contains a positive lookbehind but it seems it’s not working in Firefox and I’m getting an exception. What is the alternative to this?

Comment: Lookbehinds [aren’t supported in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665) yet. Please [edit] your question and explain _how exactly this regex is used_ in context.

Comment: Most likely, a word boundary (`\b`) would be a sufficient (but not perfectly equivalent) replacement for both lookarounds, e.g. `/\b\d(\.\d+)?\b/`. You might also try splitting the original string by spaces and parsing individual parts.

Comment: Lookbehinds are now supported since June 30, 2020 (see [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/78.0/releasenotes/))

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the positive lookbehind in a non capturing `(?:^| )` group keeping the alternation.

Then capture your value in a capturing group `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` and turn the optional decimal part also into a non capturing group. The positive lookahead is supported so you can keep that as is.

```
(?:^| )(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=$| )
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hGPIH5/1)

```js
let strings = [
  "1",
  "1.2 ",
  "0",
  "0.122",
  " 1",
  " 1.2",
  " 0",
  " 0.122",
];
let pattern = /(?:^| )(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=$| )/;
strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern)[1])
});
```